# 'Casting' C callbacks to Objective-C blocks

Tags: objective-c

I've been reading up on Objective-C blocks (e.g. in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html), [a blog post](http://cutecoder.org/programming/wrapping-style-callbacks-blocks/), and [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3915774/575530) or [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19876498/575530) or [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201774/575530) Stack Overflow answers). I want to pass a C / C++ style callback into an Objective-C method.

Here's my declaration on the C / C++ side

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef void (*CALCULATION_CALLBACK)(int x);
    void setCubeCallback(int x, CALCULATION_CALLBACK callback);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and in Objective-C

```
@interface IOSPluginTest : NSObject

typedef void (^CalculationHandler)(int x);
-(void)cubeThisNumber:(int)number andCallbackOn:(CalculationHandler)callback;

@end
```

And this is the Objective-C implementation

```
#import "IOSPluginTest.h"

@implementation IOSPluginTest

-(void)cubeThisNumber:(int)number andCallbackOn:(CalculationHandler)callback {
    int result = number * number * number;
    if (callback != nil) {
        callback(result);
    }
}

@end
```

Things go wrong in the last bit, the C / C++ implementation

```
void setCubeCallback(int x, CALCULATION_CALLBACK callback) {
    [[[IOSPluginTest alloc] init] cubeThisNumber:x andCallbackOn:callback];
}
```

which fails to compile with the error

> Sending 'CALCULATION_CALLBACK' (aka 'void(*)(int)') to parameter of incompatible type 'CalculationHandler' (aka 'void(^)(int)')

Those two type descriptions, `void(*)(int)` and `void(^)(int)`, look pretty similar to me; what am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913627/converting-a-function-pointer-to-a-block-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um, "[types] look pretty similar" doesn't count for much in programming.

What you're missing is that blocks and function pointers are different types of things.

A function pointer is pretty much just the address of the first instruction of the function's code.

A block is an object. Among the data held by that object is a function pointer, but it also has other data. Beyond the basic infrastructure for being an object (such as the `isa` pointer), blocks can capture variable values from their definition site.

You can use function pointers in Objective-C just fine. If you want your two interfaces to be directly compatible, just use `CALCULATION_CALLBACK` as the type of the `callback` parameter in the Objective-C method.

Alternatively, you can wrap the function pointer in a block, like so:

```
void setCubeCallback(int x, CALCULATION_CALLBACK callback) {
    [[[IOSPluginTest alloc] init] cubeThisNumber:x andCallbackOn:^(int result){ callback(result); }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`void(*)(int)` is a method pointer `void(^)(int)` a block, in other languages called closure. They are fundamentally different. While method pointers just do that — point to a method —, blocks also carry data by encapsulation. This things are very different, it makes no sense to try to cast them form one to the other.

But you can use C method pointers in Objective-C.